# Validate at least one checkbox has been checked

Tags: .net, powershell, checkbox

I'm interested in having the user at least check one option. It's not important how many, but at least one needs to be checked. And if not, an error needs to be generated.

Is there a way to do this with a `GroupBox` or another type of Container?

Here is my checkbox code:

```
$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8, 120)
$groupBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120, 144)
$groupBox1.TabIndex = 0
$groupBox1.TabStop = $false
$groupBox1.Text = 'Options:'

$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8, 8)
$checkBox1.TabIndex = 1
$checkBox1.Text = 'Banana'

$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox    
$checkBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8, 40)
$checkBox2.TabIndex = 2
$checkBox2.Text = 'Apple'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done using an if-test, like:

```
if($checkBox1.Checked -or $checkBox2.Checked) {
    #Continue work
}
```

When should it check?

- **When you click a button?** Add the if-test inside your button's click-eventhandler.
- **Should a button be disabled(greyed out) until the button is checked?**
  Add the if-test and enable/disable button code to the checkboxes checked-eventhandler.

If this is checked when a button is clicked, and you only want to generate the error, then:

```
if(-not($checkBox1.Checked -or $checkBox2.Checked)) {
    #Throw exception
    Write-Error No checkboxes checked

    #Error popup only
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Check minimum one checkbox!",
                                    "ERROR",
                                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
                                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error) | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: This method will work but is not very scalable. If you have 30 options in a group, you don't really want to write out up to `-or $checkBox30.Checked` in your code.